# Table relation with stored procedure and trigger

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

To make it simple I have this:

C# form --> tableA (via stored procedure)

What I am trying to achieve:

C# form --> tableA --> tableB

Info sent from C# form to table A. From table A I want to send a related column to Table B

```
TableA (ProfileID) = Table B (UserID)
```

So, I created a trigger on my stored procedure that is connected with the c# form:

```
ALTER TRIGGER IDs
ON  dbo.UserProfile
FOR INSERT
AS
   DECLARE @ProfileID int

   SELECT 
        ProfileID
   FROM
        dbo.UserProfile

   INSERT INTO  dbo.Users(Users.UserID)
   VALUES(@ProfileID)
GO
```

But when my stored procedure is being executed from C# form, I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'UserID'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a *lot* of things wrong with your trigger code.. Maybe you should just have the form, or the sproc, do the extra inserts?

Comment: Agree with Blorgbeard. If you wrap the 2 inserts within a single transaction, you get same effect with less risk.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I am new to triggers, can you explain what is wrong? What I am trying to do is: whenever a new insertion is made from the form into the table, the field from table A (which is being auto incremented) also goes into table B. If there is an easier way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: Briefly: @ProfileID is never assigned anything; that select is just throwing away its results. It's also just selecting everything in the table, not what was just inserted. And you only have a single `@ProfileID` - a trigger can be executed once for many rows inserted. You need to access the `inserted` virtual table. I suspect you need to learn a bit more about TSQL scripting to get this done with a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments on question, it is probably better to put your inserts into a transaction in the stored proc already called, but if you must do a trigger, this is about what it should look like. Note the specific name and then the insert being done from the INSERTED table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER UserProfile_CreateUser
ON  dbo.UserProfile
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Users (UserID)
        SELECT ProfileID
        FROM INSERTED
END
GO
```

For more info on virtual tables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think using a trigger in this case might not be the best solution.

Comment: I'm looking into transactions and the examples I am seeing all have hard coded values into SET and WHERE, if I were to do this transaction how will I achieve this: SET userID = ProfileID, WHERE...